# I want to storage data from html forms. But I want to make it saved to a local file (a text or csv file - for categorization - )

Tags: javascript, python, html, local-storage, css-tables

I have a project which is for saving some films that i watched. Its a listing website.
Part 1# (Entry Panel) I will have a panel which includes a form that i input the film's specifications(name,category,actors etc.). Then when i click the submit button it will save the data locally (in a csv or txt file). Of course i should be able to append new films to that file.
Part 2# (viewer) And in the main page i need to see the films as lines in a HTML table. The table will be filled by the datas from the file i saved (Js loops will be needed i guess). If that topic is different than i ask, if there is another way, please manage me how to search. Im thinking that i must learn SQL for more complicated data storages.
Here is the simple website:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Film Lister</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="movie-name">
        <input type="text" name="movie-category">
        <button type="submit">Append the movie to file</button>
    </form>
    
    <table id="showcase">
        <tr class="movie">
            <td class="movie-spec"></td>
            <td class="movie-spec"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="movie">
            <td class="movie-spec"></td>
            <td class="movie-spec"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        //The part i need help
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Data like that is typically stored on the server; and in-browser JavaScript has no direct access to the hard drive anyway. You could use localStorage instead, but if you accidentally delete it or want to use another browser, the data is gone. I recommend learning basic PHP and mySQL and installing [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). This question is also way too broad for this website; you essentially want beginner's tutorials and the web is full of those.

Answer (score 0):

Well, saving data with JavaScript is fairly easy to achieve:

```
    // Save as File
    function download(filename, text) {
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);

      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);

      element.click();

      document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Call with:

```
var csvContents = "1,2,3,4,5";
download("mydata.csv", csvContents);
```

You will need to figure out how `csvContents` will be constructed though.

I would advise you to learn jQuery as it is very easy for modifying or creating HTML/DOM elements (which is what you require here). Note that this is from someone who is by no means a web application expert and is from a different domain.

**NOTE:** If you want to append to the file, you need permissions, which you don't have over the your system from a browser. You should consider using a database.